# C# Checkedlistbox if checked

Tags: c#, checkbox

Is it possible to apply .Checked== to checkedlistbox as in checkbox?

If to do it in a way as with checkbox it not works

```
if(checkedListBox1.Items[2].Checked==true)
{
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need is the method `GetItemCheckState`.

Usage as follows:

```
if(checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(2) == CheckState.Checked)
{

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use it in this way

```
if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Contains("ItemWithIndex2"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

Comment: this could result in wrong behaviour if there are several items with the same name

Answer (score 3):

Try something like...

```
checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i)

foreach(int indexChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices) {
    // The indexChecked variable contains the index of the item.
    MessageBox.Show("Index#: " + indexChecked.ToString() + ", is checked. Checked state is:" +
                    checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(indexChecked).ToString() + ".");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetItemChecked()` returns a boolean value. So you can use it as the following:

```
if(checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(index) == true) {

}
```

Where `index` is an integer value denoting the row index of `checkedListBox1`.

Answer (score 0):

`GetItemCheckState()` returns a boolean value. So you can use as follows:

```
if(checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(index) == true)
{

}
```

where index is an integer value denoting the row index of CheckedListBox

Answer (score 0):

you might be looking for something like this

```
foreach(int i in checkedListBox1.SelectedIndices)
        {
            if(checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i)!=CheckState.Checked)
            {
                ....
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue: On a click of an item, the state should be converted from either checked/ non-checked to opposite. Here i post the event and the check and change:

```
    CheckedListBox ChkLBox;
    private void CheckedListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int SelectedIndex = ChkLBox.SelectedIndex; //
        var Item = ChkLBox.Items[SelectedIndex];

        bool IsChecked = (ChkLBox.GetItemChecked(ChkLBox.SelectedIndex));
        ChkLBox.SetItemChecked(ChkLBox.Items.IndexOf(Item), !IsChecked);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count>0

Answer (score -1):

```
var itemChecked = checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Code-only answers are not ideal, you should consider adding some explanations.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure i understand your question, do you want to check if at least 1 item in the listbox is checked? If so you could do that

```
if(checkedListBox1.Items.Any(item=>item.Checked))
{
}
```

Comment: `Items` contains strings, so `item.Checked` won't work