# Get value from all checked CheckListBox items

Tags: c#

Why can't I get specific value of an item?

```
List<int> IdFundosSelecionados = new List<int>();

for(int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if(checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        IdFundosSelecionados.Add(checkedListBox1.Items[i].value) //it isn't working
    }             
}
```

OBS: I would like to get the CHECKED values not the selected (it's different from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074470/c-sharp-checkedlistbox-if-checked))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Checkedlistbox if checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074470/c-sharp-checkedlistbox-if-checked)

Comment: @MethodMan the questions are similar but are not the same

Comment: @MethodMan No , I have read both questions , and this fellow isn't trying to see if checkbox is checked but rather he is trying to understand why he's unable to insert the checked box text into his list .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this will solve your problem :

```
for(int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if(checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
        {
           IdFundosSelecionados.Add(((int)checkedListBox1.Items[i]))
        } 
}
```

btw have you tried this ?

```
 List<int> IdFundosSelecionados = new List<int>();

    for(int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if(checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            IdFundosSelecionados.Add(checkedListBox1.Items[i].text)  
        }             
    }
```

My favorite eazy one would be (personal opinion) :

```
List<int> IdFundosSelecionados = new List<int>();
foreach (ListItem li1 in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
                {
                    if (li1.Selected == true) 
                    {
                      IdFundosSelecionados.Add(li1.Text)  

                    }
                }
```

Comment: second approach should be the answer vs your first.. I only say that because it would be best to iterate if you were to use the fist answer

Comment: @MethodMan You mean I have to show the loop? I appreciate improvement suggestions

Comment: "Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.DataRowView'"

Comment: @RandRandom Ohhh...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you add your items to the CheckedListBox, but you just need to cast the items to whatever object type you added them as. Then once you have the original type, you can convert it to int however you need (since IdFundosSelecionades is List).

For example...

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(i);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
            IdFundosSelecionades.Add((int)checkedListBox1.Items[i]); 
            // added as int, so cast as int
    }
}
```